# Static object localization using single moving camera ( Camera Real world position is known)

Tags: localization, computer-vision

We have:

- Moving camera C
- Static object O
- I1 , I2 are images taken by Camera C at time points t1,t2
- x1,y1 are center coordinates of the object O in I1
- x2,y2 are center coordinates  of the object O in I2
- P1 , P2 are the 3d positions of the camera C in the real world at time points t1,t2

Given x1,x2,y1,y2,P1,P2 how to calculate the the position of the object in the real world (P_obj)

Answer (score 0):

This is epipolar geometry (https://docs.opencv.org/master/da/de9/tutorial_py_epipolar_geometry.html)  and stereo triangulation (https://docs.opencv.org/master/dd/d53/tutorial_py_depthmap.html).  You'll need to know camera parameters (focal length, resolution, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

After long search I found a video which can be useful, especially starting from minute 19:00:
[Epipolar Geometry III](https://www.coursera.org/lecture/robotics-perception/epipolar-geometry-iii-Bwk0d)